# Getting 404 for URL /adfs/ls in SP initiated sign on

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs, single-sign-on

I have done configurations to set up SSO using ADFS (on windows server 2012 R2) and shibboleth (on Ubuntu 12.x box).

Whenever I do SP initiated sign on i.e. https://mywebapp.com/authsml; the URL gets redirected to https://myfederation-service-name/adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=aSamlRequest;
which i think is right.

But I get following error:

> The requested URL /adfs/ls/ was not found on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Other facts I checked are:

- ADFS is running on port 443.
- The URL https://myfederation-service-name/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx works inside the IE browser of my windows server where ADFS is deployed.
- Since Windows server is on AWS, I have also made sure that All the inbound connections are Allowed on port 443.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the hostname `myfederation-service-name` resolvable via DNS from all involved hosts?

Comment: @Andrew I have done ping to <myfederation-service-name> from Ubuntu machine as well as from external windows machine. And it worked. Any other way to ensure?

Comment: well, in theory the ping would require that the DNS resolution works, but using the `host` command (in *nix) would query directly via DNS. You will likely have to check the logs from all involved systems to see where the failure is occurring. There are also SAML inspection tools you can use inside web browsers to help troubleshoot this

Comment: @Andrew host command in my ubuntu box resolves correctly. I'm using one saml debugger extension but it's not helping much. There are no error logs at shibboleth side. And Adfs logs don't say much too. But I have found out that I/m missing this  in my config at windows server: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ff641704(v=ws.10)#determine-whether-ad-fs-20-sites-are-missing-in-iis-or-whether-they-have-been-enabled  And I dont know how to go about it.